# How can I spectate VS games in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: pc, steam, left-4-dead-2

Is there a way to enable players to connect to connect as spectators to a VS game in Left 4 Dead 2? And how can I do it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't spectate a full game unless the server has enabled [SourceTV](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SourceTV).  If SourceTV is enabled, the server will have it listening for connections on a different port, usually 5 above the server's normal port (so, port 27020 by default).

Answer (score 1):

They can connect normally and choose to spectate but they are still counted towards the "Players" count of up to 8.

So to answer your question, no. You cant have additional spectators connected.

Comment: Is there now way to configure the server so it will allow the connection of more than 8 people?